# Swift3　PageViewControllerでの画面移動の際の値の渡し方

Tags: swift3

Swift3にて、tableViewControllerのセルのindexによって画面遷移先を指定し、遷移した先の画面同士でページ移動できるようにし、tableView（初期画面）に戻る時はNavigationControllerの戻るボタンで戻れるアプリを作りたいと思っております。

＜苦戦しているところ＞
tableViewControllerのあるviewControllerからpageViewControllerにセグエで接続し、pageViewControllerからそれぞれページを表示させているのですが、その際に次のページに値(index)を渡そうとしているのですが、うまくいきません。

※ viewControllerにはNavigationControllerをEmbedしてあります。

TableViewControllerのあるViewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var indexCell:Int?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


(略）

//セルを作る
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    let cellData = section0[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = cellData.0
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = cellData.1
    return cell
}


//セルがタップされた時の処理
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
    indexCell = indexPath.row
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue1",sender: self)

}

//セグエで移動する前にデータを受け渡す
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "segue1" {
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {     
            tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)      
            if let pvc = segue.destination as? PageViewController {
                pvc.received = indexCell       
            }
        }
    }
}


}
```

pageViewController

```
class PageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

var contentVCs = [UIViewController]()

var select:Int?

//遷移後に渡される値を格納する
var received:Int?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    dataSource = self
    delegate = self

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let fvc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstViewController") as! FirstViewController
    fvc.received = received
    let svc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
    svc.received = received
    let tvc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ThirdViewController") as! ThirdViewController
    tvc.received = received

    contentVCs.append(fvc)
    contentVCs.append(svc)
    contentVCs.append(tvc)

    // タップされたcellのindexによって表示VCを分岐
    switch received! {
        case 0,3,6,9,12,15,18 :
        select = 0
        case 1,4,7,10,13,16,19 :
        select = 1
        case 2,5,8,11,14,17,20 :
        select = 2
    default :
        break
    }

    setViewControllers([contentVCs[select!]], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

}


// MARK: - UIPageViewControllerDataSource

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    guard let index = contentVCs.index(of: viewController), index != NSNotFound else { return nil }
    if index < contentVCs.count - 1 {
        return contentVCs[index + 1]
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    guard let index = contentVCs.index(of: viewController), index != NSNotFound else { return nil }
    if index > 0 {
        return contentVCs[index - 1]
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
}
```

FirstViewController（second,thirdも同じ）

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var indexLabel: UILabel!

//シーン移動の際に設定されるデータ
var received:Int?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


// 受取りdata確認用ラベル
indexLabel.text = String(received!)

}

}
```

このコードだと、セルのindex通りのvcを選んで表示されるのですが、ページをめくると同じindex番号のまま（タップした時のセルのindex)になってしまいます。ページが進んだらindex番号もカウントアップさせたりダウンさせたりしたいのですが、Before/Afterのところで値を渡せたらいいのかと思いましたが、適切なコードが書けず苦戦しております。
長くなりましたが、分かる方いらっしゃいましたらご教授お願い致します。

＜回答を参考に修正したコード＞

```
// MARK: - UIPageViewControllerDataSource

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    guard let index = contentVCs.index(of: viewController), index != NSNotFound else { return nil }
    let nextIndex = index + 1
    if index == 0 {
        if let nextVC = contentVCs[nextIndex] as? SecondViewController {
            nextVC.received = nextIndex 
            return nextVC
        }
        return nil
    } else if index == 1 {
        if let nextVC = contentVCs[nextIndex] as? ThirdViewController {
            nextVC.received = nextIndex
            return nextVC
        }
        return nil
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    guard let index = contentVCs.index(of: viewController), index != NSNotFound else { return nil }
    let nextIndex = index - 1
    if index == 2 {
        if let nextVC = contentVCs[nextIndex] as? SecondViewController {
            nextVC.received = nextIndex
            return nextVC
        }
        return nil
    } else if index == 1 {
        if let nextVC = contentVCs[nextIndex] as? FirstViewController {
            nextVC.received = nextIndex
            return nextVC
        }
        return nil
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afterなら`return contentVCs[index + 1]`としてるところで、

```
// return contentVCs[index + 1]
let nextIndex = index + 1
if let nextVC = contentVCs[nextIndex] as? FirstViewController {
    nextVC.received = nextIndex
    return nextVC
}
return nil
```

ですね。

ここでデータを渡そうというのは正しいと思います。「適切なコードが書けず」とのことですが、`ViewController`の配列に格納した遷移先のビューコントローラを`FirstViewController`のインスタンスとしてキャストせずにいて`received`にアクセスできなかったのではないでしょうか。このような場合は `as` を使った型キャストが必要です。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。教えて頂いたコードでページ移動の際に値を渡せるようになりました。大変助かりました。ありがとうご‌​ざいました。ですが、渡したい値をrece‌​ived（セルをタップした時のindex‌​（表示させるvcの数よりセル数の方が多い‌​ので）)にしたいのですが、nextVC.‌​received= received+1とすると１つ先のページと２つ先のページが同じ値になってしまいます。（nextIndexの‌​場合ではちゃんと+1ずつ更新されてアップ‌​されています）もし解決方法が分かるようで‌​したら教えて頂けると助かります。

Comment: `ViewController`の`prepare()`で`pvc.received = indexCell`してから、`PageViewController`の`received`の値が変更されてないからでしょうね。ずっとタップしたセルのインデックスのままです。`Before`/`After`でそれに`+1`/`-1`したものを表示されるページに渡してるだけではそうなります

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。他の方法を試したのですが、結局解決できず、どうすれば渡す値が更新されるのでしょうか？

Comment: こちらは`pageViewController`と`First...`/`Second...`/`Third`の`received`に何が格納されるべきか設計意図が全くわからないので正しいコードを示しようがないですよ。現段階で4つある`received`にはそれぞれ何が入るべきなんですか

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。最初のreceivedにはtableViewのcellをタップした時のindexが入っています。pageViewControllerに入った時はタップされたcellのindex番号のvcを表示させるようにし、ページをめくるごとに合わせてindex番号もカウントアップさせたいです。というのも、cellのindex番号によってvcに表示させる内容を変えるためです。receivedに入れたindex番号をページごとに更新しながら渡したいのですが、cellの数とvcの数が違うので、pageViewControllerのところの配列contentVCsのindex番号のままだとcellのindex番号と同じではなくなってしまいます。pageViewcontrollerの配列contentVCsに追加しFirst/Second/ThirdVCはcellの数より少ないので条件分岐させて表示させようと思っています。

Comment: 設計が間違っています。ほとんどの場合、ビューコントローラはそのように再利用するべきではありません。既存のインスタンスにデータを再セットするのではなく、ページごとに適切なクラスで新規生成するべきだと思います。特にページビューコントローラは表示中のページの前後のビューコントローラも自動的に生成します。`Before`/`After`でデータをセットしていますが、もし同じインスタンスが隣同士になった場合、先読みしたページにセットしたデータが現在のページに表示されることもあります

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。当方、素人なのであまり難しいことは分かりませんが、cellの数と同じ数ののviewControllerを生成した方がよい。もしくはページビューコントローラーを利用しない他の方法をとった方がよいということでしょうか。

Comment: セルの数と同じだけ生成する必要はないし、ページビューコントローラを使うのは正しいです。足りないのは表示中のページのインデックスを動的に取得する方法です。最初に得たインデックスを`+1`/`-1`して現在のインデックスとするのは無理です。インデックスを更新する最適なタイミングのイベントをページビューコントローラがくれないので。最初の質問内容とはもうかけ離れているので新しい質問でも立ててください。「ページビューコントローラのページをインデックスで管理する方法」を前提に「現在表示中のページのインデックスを得る方法」を訊くといいです

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。作りたいのはまさに(githubのアプリ)その通りです。丁寧に教えて頂いてありがとうございました。